# license for package Android SDK Platform 27

Tags: ionic3, ionic4

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.

  > You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
  >   [Android SDK Platform 27].
  >   Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  >   Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 21s
(node:6780) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Comment: i am using this command to accenpt licence agreement but donot works  " android update sdk --no-ui 
--filter build-tools-
26,android-24,extra-
android-m2repository"

Comment: i am using Cordova Android 7.1.0

Answer (score 0):

I got slolution run this command 
**android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter build-tools-27,android-27,extra-android-m2repository**